# tick function is not working in aframe 0.8.2

Tags: aframe

I was trying to use tick function as described in the below link https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/introduction/best-practices.md but it didnt worked out

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  tick: function () {
    var el = this.el;
    var rotationTmp = this.rotationTmp = this.rotationTmp || {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0};
    var rotation = el.getAttribute('rotation');
    rotationTmp.x = rotation.x + 0.1;
    rotationTmp.y = rotation.y;
    rotationTmp.z = rotation.z;
    el.setAttribute('rotation', rotationTmp);
  }
});
```

Expected output the object should rotate around x actual result nothing happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it's okay if i clarify a bit Kevin's answer.

But first of all, the code is working.  Both in aframe [0.9.2](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/wxvtycmg/11/) and [0.8.2](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/wxvtycmg/10/).
The issue may be related to

- the script being placed after the scene is loaded
- the component not being attached to the entity:

js:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
   // component body
})
```

html:

```
<a-entity foo></a-entity>
```

---

As for Kevins answer - it may be a good idea to make changes in the `tick` function with referring to the underlying `THREE.js` object.

If you want to rotate a box, there's no need to throw in all that logic you have:
1) create a tmp variable
2) get the object rotation 
3) set the tmp variable
4) set the object rotation

When you have a function which executes on each render loop (`tick`) then you want to minimize what's happening there. So Kevin directly accesses the `THREE.js` object, and changes the rotation:

```
tick: function() {
   el.object3D.rotation.x += 0.1 * Math.PI / 180 // three uses radians
}
```

Check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/wxvtycmg/14/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `el.object3D.rotation.x += 0.1`

Comment: Can you explain that further? What does that code do, and what makes you think that it solves the problem?